# sql left join select all records from left table even if no records in rigth table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run following query :

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) + b.item_opening_balance as closing
FROM transaction_inventory AS a 
LEFT JOIN inventory_master as b
ON b.item_code = a.item_code and b.company_code = a.company_code
WHERE a.item_Code = 2222
      AND a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
      AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
  AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01' ;
```

How do i select records from inventory_master even if there are not records in transaction_inventory ? currently its giving null value for **b.item_opening_balance** which should give the actual item opening balance from master table.

Putting a sub query like

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) +
(select item_opening_balance from inventory_master where item_code = a.item_code) as closing
FROM transaction_inventory AS a 
WHERE a.item_Code = 2222
  AND a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
  AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
  AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01'
```

returns the item opening balance from inventory_master, but i am avoiding to use subquery

Comment: if you want to display inventory_master data irrespective of the fact that transaction_inventory is null or not  user RIGHT JOIN and if you can allow inventory_master or transaction_inventory to be null as well  use FULL OUTER JOIN replica in mysql , check my answer

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan MySQL has no FULL OUTER JOIN support. You have to play with left/right joins to achieve that result

Comment: @NitinKabra Anyway, regardless of your query... what output are you expecting?

Comment: You should try with RIGHT JOIN

Comment: does Select count(*) from inventory_master where item_name is null; return more than 0? If so, it is a data issue, not a query issue. Fix your data.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Use Left Join  & Right Join Union to get FULL JOIN

Comment: well putting a sub query like (select item_name from inventory_master where item_code = a.item_code) returns the item name from inventory_master. but i am avoiding to use subquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an outer join if you want all records from one of the tables.

```
select ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) as aa,b.item_name,a.item_Code from  transaction_inventory AS a right outer join inventory_master as b
on b.item_code = a.item_code and b.company_code = a.company_code
WHERE  a.item_Code = 2222
       and a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
       AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
       AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01' ;
```

If you reorder your from clause, you can also use a left outer join:

```
select ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) as aa,b.item_name,a.item_Code from   inventory_master as b left outer join transaction_inventory AS a
on b.item_code = a.item_code and b.company_code = a.company_code
WHERE  a.item_Code = 2222
       and a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
       AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
       AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01' ;
```

Use left outer join if the left table is the one to have all records returned, regardless of null values in the right one, or right outer join if the table with all the records is on the right.

Comment: does `Select count(*) from inventory_master where item_name is null;` return more than 0?  If so, it is a data issue, not a query issue.  Fix your data.

Comment: well putting a sub query like (select item_name from inventory_master where item_code = a.item_code) returns the item name from inventory_master. but i am avoiding to use subquery

Comment: I'm saying run ONLY that simple query; if it returns a value greater than zero, your problem is the data, not the query.  You will always have a null value if that is what is stored in the database and you aren't modifying the value.

Answer (score 0):

**RIGHT JOIN**

1- Will get data (Matching with inventory_master)  from transaction_inventory and NULL data as well.
2- Will **get all data** from inventory_master.

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) as aa,b.item_name,a.item_Code 
FROM transaction_inventory AS a 
RIGHT JOIN inventory_master as b
ON b.item_code = a.item_code and b.company_code = a.company_code
WHERE a.item_Code = 2222
      AND a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
      AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
  AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01' ;
```

**FULL OUTER JOIN  as UNION OF RIGHT AND LEFT JOIN **

1- Will **get all data**   from transaction_inventory and NULL data as well.
2- Will **get all data** from inventory_master and NULL data as well.

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) as aa,b.item_name,a.item_Code 
FROM transaction_inventory AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory_master as b
ON b.item_code = a.item_code and b.company_code = a.company_code
WHERE a.item_Code = 2222
      AND a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
      AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
  AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01' ;

UNION

SELECT ifnull(sum(item_actual_qty),0) as aa,b.item_name,a.item_Code 
FROM transaction_inventory AS a 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inventory_master as b
ON b.item_code = a.item_code and b.company_code = a.company_code
WHERE a.item_Code = 2222
      AND a.company_code = '52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4'
      AND a.trans_type_name NOT IN ('Sales Order','Purchase Order')
  AND a.trans_date < '2010-04-01' ;
```

> as Full Join is not available , you can do full join using Right and
>   Left Join Union, example is listed below. please check

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: @Nitin Kabra Please check the updated LEFT JOIN AND RIGHT JOIN UNION

Comment: union will return two records which is not what i want. i am using this query in function.

Comment: @NitinKabra Where Clause can remove unrequired rows!